# Enumerate jpg images in folder with leading zeroes

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have a frequent task of batch renaming images in a folder such that name consists of at least two digits, e.g. `01.jpg`, `02.jpg`, `03.jpg` ... `140.jpg`.

I want to achieve it using a batch file.
I have found some code but it is renaming only first 8 images of it.

```
@echo off
set i=1

for %%f in (*.jpg)  do call :renameit "%%f"
goto done

:renameit
IF 1%i% LSS 1000 SET i=0%i%

ren %1 %i%.jpg
set /A i+=1

:done
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a DOS solution? Or are you going to run it using Windows command line (`cmd.exe`)?

Comment: i need a batch file solution

Comment: actually any script, would do the job which can run in windows

Comment: you shouldn't add a leading zero to a variable, if you want to `set /a` it later (see `set /?` for reason). Use another variable instead: `set new=0%i%` and `ren %1 %new%.jpg`

Comment: could you please post full code

Comment: your code worked stephan  but it has placed zeros before all items, I want leading zeros only before single digits. once count reaches to 10 it should not add zeros example : i need 10 not 010

Comment: then you probably should use `lss 10` instead of `lss 1000`.

Comment: with LSS 10 -> no leading zero with LSS 100 -> processing only 9 entities i.e. 01--09 , no change afterwards. and with LSS 1000 it is working but with a leading zero to all

Answer (score 1):

This task could be done with a single command line in the batch file if there are definitely never `1.jpg` and `01.jpg` in the directory and there are never `a.jpg`, `b.jpg`, etc. in the directory with the `*.jpg` files.

```
@for %%I in (?.jpg) do @ren %%I 0%%I
```

To make the batch file more useful like adding it to **Send To** folder and using it via context menu (right click) on 1 or more selected directories containing the JPEG image files, it can be extended to support optionally one or more folder paths as parameter.

```
@echo off
set "Folder=%CD%"
:NextFolder
if not "%~1" == "" set "Folder=%~f1"
if "%Folder:~-1%" == "\" set "Folder=%Folder:~0,-1%"
for %%I in ("%Folder%\?.jpg") do ren "%%~fI" "0%%~nxI"
shift
if not "%~1" == "" goto NextFolder
set "Folder="
```

This batch files renames *.jpg files with a single character as file name by default only in current directory. But if the batch file is called with 1 or more folder paths (not validated), the batch file renames `?.jpg` files in all the specified folders.

The folder paths passed to the batch file can be relative or absolute paths with or without backslash at end.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `shift /?`

Please note: The batch file is not 100% fail safe as it does not validate the folder paths or the found *.jpg files with just a single character as file name nor does it check for a file already existing with the new file name. However, error messages are printed if an error occurs like a file with new name already exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set i=1

for %%f in (*.jpg)  do call :renameit "%%f"
goto :eof

:renameit
if 1%i% lss 100 (ECHO ren %1 0%i%.jpg) else (ECHO ren %1 %i%.jpg)
set /A i+=1
goto :eof
```

did the rename directly, without a temporary variable. Remove the `ECHO`s, if the output is ok.

Comment: no its not. Actually it is not even changing the numbers.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have reached the solution by merging your two solutions.

Comment: I am posting it here for others, but the answer belongs to you

Comment: Do you even read the answers or do you only copy the code? Noticed the `Remove the ECHOs, if the output is ok.`?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a join of answers posted by stephan

```js
@echo off
set i=1

for %%f in (*.jpg)  do call :renameit "%%f"
goto done

:renameit
IF 1%i% LSS 100 (SET new=0%i%) else (SET new=%i%)
ren %1 %new%.jpg
set /A i+=1

:done
```